# How to wrap Rows which contain other widgets without overflowing in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I make multiple `Rows` each containing some widgets to wrap around without causing any overflow?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Wrap(children: [
    Row(children : [Radio(value: 'A'), Text('A')]),
    Row(children : [Radio(value: 'B'), Text('B')]),
    Row(children : [Radio(value: 'C'), Text('C')]),
    Row(children : [Radio(value: 'D'), Text('D')])
  ]);
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample layout? Looks like you could replace `Wrap` with `Column` with its size set to `minimum` so that other widget are not offscreen.

Comment: ok. i'll try yours

Comment: can you post a picture of the layout you need?

Comment: i need em to be arranged horizontally. but if overflow it is wrapped to below. reflowable like text

Comment: why not just remove the `Row` and let other widgets be direct children of `Wrap`?

Comment: because the radio button and the text is one

Comment: got it quite simple. check the answer. Like I said in the first comment to set the size to minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Row(mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,children: [Radio(value: 'A'), Text('A')]),
```

Setting the `mainAxisSize` to minimum will allow the `Row` to take as much size as it needs and not more.

[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]
[image: sample 3]

Comment: that is what i am getting with this code. Posting pics..wait

Comment: ok now it's working. sorry my misunderstanding. thank you sir for your help

Comment: is the question a duplicate?

Comment: `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min` Does the trick for me! Thank you for sharing!